# How to configure pom.xml file- spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, maven, groovy

This is my pom.xml file-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.albatrossoft</groupId>
<artifactId>wbpsc</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <war.file.name>wbpsc</war.file.name>

    <!-- NOTE: This is the default encoding that can be used everywhere -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Java Compiler plugin Target And Source -->
    <java.source.version>1.6</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.6</java.target.version>

    <!-- commons -->
    <commons-codec.version>1.7</commons-codec.version>
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.1</commons-lang.version>
    <commons-pool.version>1.6</commons-pool.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <commons-httpclient.version>3.1</commons-httpclient.version>

    <!-- javax extension -->
    <javax-mail.version>1.4.5</javax-mail.version>
    <javax-jms.version>1.1</javax-jms.version>

    <!-- infrastructure -->
    <postgresql.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.2.8</hsqldb.version>


    <!-- spring -->
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
    <spring-integration.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-integration.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- testing -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>

    <!-- ui -->
    <javax-servlet.version>2.5</javax-servlet.version>

    <!--other -->
    <jackson.version>1.9.2</jackson.version>
    <ehcache.version>4.1.7.Final</ehcache.version>
    <hibernate-core.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <jersey.version>1.17</jersey.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.19</freemarker.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.1</slf4j.version>
    <perf4j.version>0.9.12</perf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jasypt.version>1.9.0</jasypt.version>
    <fop.version>1.0</fop.version>
    <lambdaj.version>2.3.2</lambdaj.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.1</joda-time.version>
    <quartz.version>1.8.6</quartz.version>

    <google.guava.version>12.0</google.guava.version>
    <javassist.version>3.12.1.GA</javassist.version>
    <saxon.version>9.0.0.2</saxon.version>
    <jasperreports.version>5.0.0</jasperreports.version>
    <itext.version>4.2.0</itext.version>
    <groovy.version>2.0.0</groovy.version>


    <!-- supported libraries -->


    <!-- BEGIN: All plugin versions as properties SORTED by key -->

    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.2-beta-5</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.3</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
    <maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.5</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.4.1</maven-clean-plugin.version>
    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.1</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.5</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.7</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <maven-hibernate-plugin.version>2.2</maven-hibernate-plugin.version>
    <maven-install-plugin.version>2.3</maven-install-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.3.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>2.1.2</maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>

    <maven-release-plugin.version>2.1</maven-release-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-resources-plugin.version>

    <maven-scm-plugin.version>1.3</maven-scm-plugin.version>
    <maven-site-plugin.version>2.0.1</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-source-plugin.version>2.1.2</maven-source-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.11</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>2.11</maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>

    <maven-taglist-plugin.version>2.4</maven-taglist-plugin.version>
    <maven-tomcat-plugin.version>1.0</maven-tomcat-plugin.version>

    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.1</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <maven-jrebel-plugin.version>1.1.3</maven-jrebel-plugin.version>

    <!-- END: All plugin versions as properties SORTED by key -->


</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Compile Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m03</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Runtime Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>

        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Testing Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>wbpsc</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/generated-jasper</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>


    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>

            <configuration>

                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
            <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jrebel-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>bin</include>
                            <include>dist</include>
                            <include>*-testng-*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${war.file.name}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
            <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jrebel-plugin.version}</version>

        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>

            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/jasper</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/generated-jasper</outputDirectory>
                <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler</compiler>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>

                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0-beta-2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>



</profiles>
```

I am trying to run my project exceptions are as follows-

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'multiUserReport' defined in class path
>   resource [META-INF/spring/wbpsc-spring-context-jasper.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ClassgenCallback.call(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ClassgenCallback.call(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode;)V
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:779)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:964)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:549)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:527)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:504)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:240)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:490)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.loadReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.loadReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.initApplicationContext(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     ... 20 more

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Just guessing: You assigned the dependency groovy-all to *runtime*. Can you confirm that it exists in target environment?

Comment: Does the exception occur during build time or in the deployed environment?

Comment: Jasper reports v5.0.0 uses/depends on groovy-all v2.0.1. Can you try using groovy-all 2.0.1 instead of 2.0.0 in your pom? or at least remove jasper reports to check if it fixes the issue to confirm that the issue is from jasper dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to exclude Groovy as dependency from REST Assured:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Groovy because of classpath issue -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <!-- Needs to be the same version that REST Assured depends on -->
    <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There reason is that otherwise you have conflicting versions of ASM in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration of spring and hibernate works for me

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector>5.1.45</mysql.connector>
    <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- C3PO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3po.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>TestSpringHibernate</finalName>   
  </build>
```